# Wake up process in wait queue

Tags: linux, queue, kernel, sleep, wait

I am writing a Linux kernel module.
There are two processes A, B and two wait queues WQA and WQB. At the moment process A is sleeping on WQA.

I want A to be woken up when B sleeps on WQB so that when A starts B is already waiting on WQB. How can i atomically wake A and put B on WQB?

Comment: Why do you want this...?

Answer (score 2):

What about using 2 semaphores?

Process A is sleeping at semaphore A. Then process B will raise the semaphore A and request down() on semaphore B which will make him sleep. Again, once A finishes his job, it can raise semaphore B (and wake up B), and then go sleep on semaphore A.